# IS THERE ANY SOLUTIONN no imports just combinations

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
python    
def comb_gen(num_list):
num_list = [1,2,3]
```

should be output:
this should be any

```
   out_put = [{1},{2},{3},{1, 2},{2, 3},{1, 3},{1, 2, 3}]*
```

Comment: @Guy There's no dictionary there, that's a list of sets. EDIT: Oh, never mind, the question is nothing like the original. My bad.

Comment: @Raze Please ask a new question, don't edit your original question to an entirely different one.

Answer (score 1):

List is mutable structure, so you cannot have it as a key of dictionary. One solution is to convert it to `tuple`:

```py
my_dict = {"name": "John", "values": [1, 2, 3], "values2": True}

out = {tuple(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v: k for k, v in my_dict.items()}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'John': 'name', (1, 2, 3): 'values', True: 'values2'}
```

---

EDIT:

```
out = [(v, k) for k, v in my_dict.items()]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[('John', 'name'), ([1, 2, 3], 'values'), (True, 'values2')]
```

Comment: i did a mistake can you do it again

Comment: can you help again see the problem above